# How do you get the top-right corner of an image in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I want to get the top-right corner of an image in flex .... so far i can just get the x and y which are top-left by default .... sorry im a noob and if this is a dumb question

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the image width to x?

Answer (score 0):

Flex supports three coordinate systems as you will find [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=containers_intro_5.html):

> - global
> - local
> - content

Depending on how your image is laid-out you will have to use the image.x and width values and an appropriate conversion function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very involved in Flex but for flash AS2 I would do:

```
var top:Number
var right:Number

top = myImageObj._y
right = myImageObj._x + myImageObj._width
```

There might be a bit different in AS3 I think they have changed "._y" to ".Y" but I'm not sure.

Anyway the principle is the same. Use the top left and then just add the width to get the right edge

Comment: Using AS3 syntax it would be like:

top = myImageObj.y;
right = myImageObj.x + myImageObj.width;